# Templating a class on its own pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, circular-dependency

I want to template a class on its own pointer. How would I go about doing that?

```
template <typename RefType, typename X>
class Foo {
 public:
  RefType ptr;
  X val;
};
typedef Foo<Foo*, int> Type1;
typedef Foo<std::list<Foo>::iterator itr, int> Type2;
```

Basically, RefType is a type such that the `operator *` on RefType will give me an instance of the class Foo.

Any ideas on how to go about doing this in C++?

EDIT :- To give some motivation for why I'm doing this, in a downstream client code I'd like to be able to do :-

```
void clientFunc(Type1& x) {
  Type1 partner_x = *(x.partner);
}
```

without knowing the type of x.partner in advance. i.e. x.partner could be pointer or an iterator into a standard template class.

It's a very obscure use case and I could do without it, but the code would just look so much more elegant.

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: `Foo<Foo*,int>` is kind of a "recursive definition". Which kind of `Foo` should the parameter be? The same? I cannot imagine any realistic use case for such a monster type.

Comment: if `Foo<T>` is your template then `Foo<T>&` is the reference type. No need to pass it as parameter.

Comment: Why can't you just use `Foo* ptr;` in the class? The problem here is, you can't just say `Foo*`; outside the templated class declaration, you'll have to specify *which* `Foo<RefType, X>` you're talking about. Which you can't do.

Comment: This is an equivalent of pointer to pointer, so eventually you need to specify a Foo that does not point to itself.

Comment: @WilliamKappler Well, because I'm trying to keep a reference into a another container.

Comment: Your recent edit makes me this this is going to be a problem due to the language being hard-typed. Your best option might have to be an intermediate class, which will abstract these calls to suit whatever has actually been passed, much like an iterator does; my answer does not reflect that approach as it was written assuming you are, essentially, making a linked list-like assembly. An intermediate is likely going to face unnecessary overhead and complexity, though.

Comment: @WilliamKappler Yeah, it does look like having some sort of Base class would be best way to do so... Although I also like Gernot1976's answer where I only have to do one partial specialization for the pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using a base class?

```
class Base {};

template <typename RefType, typename X>
class Foo : public Base
{
 public:
  RefType ptr;
  X val;
};
typedef Foo<Base*, int> Type1;

int main()
{
    Base* p = new Type1;
    Type1* pt = static_cast<Type1*>(p);
    pt->val = 3;
    pt->ptr = new Type1;
    (static_cast<Type1*>(pt->ptr))->val = 5;

    // delete etc.
    return 0;
}
```

You could skip the casting by introducing appropriate virtual functions in the `Base`class.

**EDIT**

```
template<typename T>
class Base{
public:
    virtual Base<T>*& get_ptr() = 0;
    virtual T& get_val() = 0;
};

template <typename RefType, typename X>
class Foo : public Base<X>
{
 public:
  RefType ptr;
  X val;

  Base<X>*& get_ptr()
  {
    return ptr;
  }

  X& get_val()
  {
    return val;
  };

};
typedef Foo<Base<int>*, int> Type1;
typedef Base<int> BaseType;

int main()
{
    BaseType* p = new Type1;
    p->get_ptr() = new Type1;
    p->get_val() = 5;

    // delete etc.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like this answer because I don't have to write a partial specialization for each reference type. But it does introduce the overhead of virtual functions...

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's possible, however since your class is templated, when you declare a pointer to it in your typedef, you need to choose explicit types:

```
using Type1 = Foo<Foo<int*, int>*, int>;
```

And you can use it like so:

```
Foo<int*, int> myFoo;
int val = 42;
myFoo.ptr = &val;
myFoo.val = 64;

Type1 myObj;
myObj.val = 1337;
myObj.ptr = &myFoo;
```

With a test:

```
std::cout << *(*myObj.ptr).ptr << std::endl; // access int* on a Foo*
std::cout << (*myObj.ptr).val << std::endl; // access int on a Foo*
std::cout << myObj.val << std::endl; // access int on self
```

Prints:

> 42
>
> 64
>
> 1337

---

### EDIT

If you're looking to always have a pointer to self, then I'd eschew a `RefType` template altogether:

```
template <typename X>
struct Foo {
  Foo* ptr; // ptr to Foo<X>
  X val;
};
```

And use it like so:

```
Foo<int> first;
first.val = 42;
first.ptr = &first; // now it refers to itself.


std::cout << first.val << std::endl;

// lets go nuts:
std::cout << first.ptr->ptr->ptr->ptr->val << std::endl;
```

This is effectively the same thing as before, except now the pointed to instance of `Foo` will always be templated the same as its parent.

Comment: The inner `Foo` isn't the same type as the outer `Foo`.

Comment: @Yakk: Such a requirement was unclear to me. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that what you wrote will not compile is that Foo cannot stand without template arguments outside of its declaration, even as a pointer, such as the `Foo*` in `typedef Foo<Foo*, int> Type1;`.

If you declare the class as you have, you may recursively declare `Foo<RefType, X>` pointers in that typedef, but you'll have to have a non-`Foo*` RefType at some point for it to work. Such as:

```
typedef Foo<Foo<Foo<int*, int>*, int>*, int> Type1;
```

Which probably is not the sort of thing you want to do.

The same issue applies to `typedef Foo<std::list<Foo>::iterator itr, int> Type2;`. You cannot just say `Foo`, you must say *which* `Foo`. That's a problem, because there could be infinite recursion of the template parameters.

There are a large number of potential ways to fix this. The easiest is to modify the class declaration. This will work:

```
template<typename X>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo* ptr;
    X val;
};
typedef Foo<int> Type1;
```

If for some reason you cannot change the template, you could use a `void*` and cast it back to a fitting `Foo*`:

```
template<typename RefType, typename X>
class Foo
{
public:
    RefType ptr;
    X val;
};
typedef Foo<void*, int> Type1;

int main( )
{
    Type1 test;
    Type1* test2 = static_cast< Type1* >( test.ptr );
}
```

This is, however, notably more error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

Use [partial template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization):

```
template <typename RefType, typename X>
class Foo
{
public:
    RefType ptr;
    X val;
};

template <typename X>
class Foo<void,X>
{
public:
    using TypeSelf = Foo;
    TypeSelf* ptr;
    X val;
};

typedef Foo<void,int> Type1;
```

`Foo<void,int>` has now member `ptr` with type `Foo<void,int>*`

Comment: Doesn't compile.  There is no `Foo<int>` prior to your use of the `Foo<int>` type.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. So I'd just have to do one partial specialization for the pointer type, and the rest would just work as is?

Answer (score 1):

Turning [jenas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34362879/templating-a-class-on-its-own-pointer/34363271#34363271)'s answer on it's head:

Instead of making a base class, derive from Foo and use that instead of a typedef. This is similar to CRTP.

```
struct Type1 : public Foo<Type1 *, int> { };
struct Type2 : public Foo<std::list<Type2>::iterator, int> { };
```

You can use Type1 and Type2 like a typedef.